# JSON.parse: Unable to find error in code

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a script receiving a JSON from PHP. I have to parse the data. Unfortunately I'm not able to parse the JSON into an object and get the different arrays. I tried to validate the JSON but I cant find an error there either.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "html",
  url: "/sqldblink.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    var recdata=data;
    console.log("Received data from listregistered:");
    console.log("Server reports:" + recdata);
    ListRegisteredResults(recdata);
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("Failed to list!");
   }
});

function ListRegisteredResults(recdata) {
    console.log(typeof recdata);
    var data = JSON.parse(recdata);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof data);
    console.log(data.Address.length);
}
```

The output:

```
Server reports:"{\"Address\":[\"Home\",\"\",\"Home,\nHoover House 85\",\"\",\"Home\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\"],\"BloodGroup\":[\"o+\",\"\",\"B+\",\"B+\",\"AB+\",\"o+\",\"o-\",\"\",\"\",\"\"],\"Occupation\":[\"Vendor\",\"\",\"Carpenter\",\"Playing\",\"Nurse\",\"IT professional\",\"Engineer\",\"Doctor\",\"\",\"\"],\"Alternate\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"925\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"],\"Email\":[\"some@site.com\",\"\",\"jim@site.com\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"arun@site.com\",\"\",\"\",\"\"],\"Mobile\":[\"90000006\",\"90000005\",\"90000005\",\"34344444\",\"902w0w05\",\"90002005\",\"900020w5\",\"90000005\",\"90002105\",\"90000005\"],\"Marital\":[\"Married\",\"Married\",\"Married\",\"Unmarried\",\"Unmarried\",\"Married\",\"Married\",\"Married\",\"Married\",\"Married\"],\"Gender\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"\",\"1\",\"1\",\"2\",\"2\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\"],\"Age\":[\"28\",\"65\",\"35\",\"2\",\"25\",\"34\",\"31\",\"28\",\"60\",\"58\"],\"Name\":[\"Tracy Jim\",\"George Jose\",\"Jim G Mathew\",\"Cary jim\",\"Becky Mathew\",\"Cary Guy\",\"Arun Mose\",\"Tracy Kelly\",\"Dr Kim\",\"Steven Ludwig\"],\"HospitalID\":[\"3\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\",\"8\",\"9\",\"10\",\"11\",\"12\",\"16\"]}"
string
{"Address":["Home","","Home,\nHoover House 85","","Home","","","","",""],"BloodGroup":["o+","","B+","B+","AB+","o+","o-","","",""],"Occupation":["Vendor","","Carpenter","Playing","Nurse","IT professional","Engineer","Doctor","",""],"Alternate":["0","0","925","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],"Email":["some@site.com","","jim@site.com","","","","arun@site.com","","",""],"Mobile":["90000006","90000005","90000005","34344444","902w0w05","90002005","900020w5","90000005","90002105","90000005"],"Marital":["Married","Married","Married","Unmarried","Unmarried","Married","Married","Married","Married","Married"],"Gender":["1","2","","1","1","2","2","1","1","1"],"Age":["28","65","35","2","25","34","31","28","60","58"],"Name":["Tracy Jim","George Jose","Jim G Mathew","Cary jim","Becky Mathew","Cary Guy","Arun Mose","Tracy Kelly","Dr Kim","Steven Ludwig"],"HospitalID":["3","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","16"]}
string
userjs/main.js:347 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ListRegisteredResults (userjs/main.js:347)
    at Object.success (userjs/main.js:295)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

After I parse the string into JSON, why is it still being reported as being a string?

Comment: What does `console.log(data.Address);` say?

Comment: Well if `string` is the result of that last `console.log(typeof data);`, then you mustn’t wonder much ...

Comment: @Cerbrus undefined

Comment: My guess is the data sent by the server literally has outer quotes. In line with CBroe's comment, it's probably a JSON representation of a string, not a representation of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `dataType: "html"` as well as any `JSON.parse()` from your code and it'll work. jQuery automatically parses the data if you don't set wrong dataTypes, or `json`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/sqldblink.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    var recdata=data;
    console.log("Received data from listregistered:");
    console.log("Server reports:" + recdata);
    ListRegisteredResults(recdata);
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("Failed to list!");
   }
});

function ListRegisteredResults(recdata) {
    console.log(typeof recdata);
    var data = recdata;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof data);
    console.log(data.Address.length);
}
```

Comment: Cool.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You JSON was invalid. `\n` at position `28` was breaking it, you need to escape it.

`"Address":["Home","","Home,\nHoover House 85"`

Should be

`"Address":["Home","","Home,\\nHoover House 85"`

If you want to keep that `\n`.

```js
let jsonString = `{"Address":["Home","","Home,\\nHoover House 85","","Home","","","","",""],"BloodGroup":["o+","","B+","B+","AB+","o+","o-","","",""],"Occupation":["Vendor","","Carpenter","Playing","Nurse","IT professional","Engineer","Doctor","",""],"Alternate":["0","0","925","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],"Email":["some@site.com","","jim@site.com","","","","arun@site.com","","",""],"Mobile":["90000006","90000005","90000005","34344444","902w0w05","90002005","900020w5","90000005","90002105","90000005"],"Marital":["Married","Married","Married","Unmarried","Unmarried","Married","Married","Married","Married","Married"],"Gender":["1","2","","1","1","2","2","1","1","1"],"Age":["28","65","35","2","25","34","31","28","60","58"],"Name":["Tracy Jim","George Jose","Jim G Mathew","Cary jim","Becky Mathew","Cary Guy","Arun Mose","Tracy Kelly","Dr Kim","Steven Ludwig"],"HospitalID":["3","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","16"]}`;

let json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(json.Address);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening only because of `dataType: "html"`, that you are sending with your post request. SO the response you are getting with '\' so `JSON.parse()` can't handle them. 
Remove `dataType` from post request and then try, then you'll get correct response and your required result.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/sqldblink.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    var recdata=data;
    console.log("Received data from listregistered:");
    console.log("Server reports:" + recdata);
    ListRegisteredResults(recdata);
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("Failed to list!");
   }
});

function ListRegisteredResults(recdata) {
    console.log(typeof recdata);
    var data = JSON.parse(recdata);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof data);
    console.log(data.Address.length);
}
```